# Simplify addition with 0.0

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics, core-language

When I enter `f + 0` where `f` is an undefined symbol, I get `f`. So far so good. When I enter `f + 0.`, I get `f + 0.`. How can I get Mathematica to simplify 0. just like it does for 0? I tried using `Simplify`, I got the same result.

Comment: Because  `f+0.` is not same as `f`. Compare `Pi+0` and `Pi+0.` The latter is a machine precision number. Run `#[Pi + 0, Pi + 0.] & /@ {SameQ, Equal}` to see the difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another reason why `0.` is not removed is that it is an [inexact](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html) zero.  In other words, it represents something that is zero to a certain precision, but unknown beyond that.

The usual way to convert very small inexact numbers to an exact zero is [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html).  An exact zero will be removed immediately.

```
Chop[f + 0.]
(* f *)
```

I do not recommend using a replacement rule to remove it.  Why?  It's because replacement rules use patterns, which will match only on *structurally identical* expressions (not mathematically equal ones).  There are several structurally different expressions which look like zero and are effectively zero. Yet a simple pattern will only match one of them.  Try e.g. ``` f + 0.``20 ```, or a "no precision left" zero arising from catastrophic cancellation.

Answer (score 6):

As @BlacKow pointed out `Pi+0.` differs from `Pi` so Mathematica is right not to remove the `+0.`.  One option is to use a replacement rule

```
f+0. /. {x_+0.:>x}
```

Comment: You can also do `f + 0. /. 0. -> 0`, or `f + 0. // Chop`.

Answer (score 6):

From the doc :

> - Chop[expr,delta] replaces numbers smaller in absolute magnitude than
>     delta by 0.
> - Chop uses a default tolerance of 10^-10.

Accordingy :

```
Chop[f + 1. 10^-20]
```

gives :

> f

You might want very small values not to canceled. In that case you can use the two arguments syntax of `Chop`:

```
Chop[f + 1. 10^-20, 10^-30]
```

> 1.*10^-20 + f

But if you have no idea of the magnitude of what is negligible or not, it seems that you can use `Rationalize[..., 0]` :

```
Rationalize[f + 0., 0]
```

> f

```
Rationalize[f + 1. 10^-20, 0]
```

> 1/100000000000000005484 + f

and then return to classic machine-precision number :

```
N[Rationalize[f + 1. 10^-20, 0]]
```

> 1.*10^-20 + f